# Не работает findByUsername JpaRepository

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, repository, bean

У меня никак не получается исправить следующую ошибку, помогите, пожалуйста, не понимаю, в чем проблема. Ошибка при добавлении @Autowired
UserRepository userRepository; в классе Impl но я не знаю, как это исправить

```
Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.example.demo6.repository.UserRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

[image: Структура проекта]

AppConfig

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({ "com.example.demo6" })

public class AppConfig {
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        //return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        return PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder(); // with new spring security 5
    }
    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver
                = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        //viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }
}
```

WebSecurityConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan({ "com.example.demo6.*" })
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private final UserRepository userRepository;

public UserDetailsServiceImpl(final UserRepository userRepository){
    this.userRepository=userRepository;
}

    @Autowired
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
        return authProvider;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().
                antMatchers("/index", "/user","/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/admin").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/admin", true) // It renders a login form
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"));
    }

}
```

Impl

```
@Service
@ComponentScan("com.example.demo6.dao.impl.*")
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        final User user = userRepository.findByEmail(email);
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(name);
        }
        UserDetails returnUser = User.withUsername(user.getUsername())
                .password(user.getPassword())
                .authorities("USER").build();
        return user;
    }
}
```

Repo

```
package com.example.demo6.repository;
import com.example.demo6.entity.User;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    User findByEmail(String email);
}
```

Comment: не может найти репозиторий. Попробуй проставить `@ComponentScan("com.example.demo6.dao.impl.*")` над `UserDetailsServiceImpl`

Comment: вообще должен и так находить если у тебя `spring-boot` и включен `EnableAutoConfiguration`..

Comment: отпишись если что получится или нет

Comment: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.example.demo6.repository.UserRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}

Comment: мне нужно сделать без использования Spring Boot

Comment: `No qualifying bean of type 'com.example.demo6.repository.UserRepository'` как видите он ищет в `com.example.demo6.repository`

Comment: AppConfig приложите

Comment: ок  теперь приложено

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133152/discussion-between---and-mak).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Обзор

К сожалению, на поисках бина `userRepository`, история не закончится, потому что:

1. после этого он не сможет найти `entityManager`,
2. после чего не сможет найти `dataSource`,
3. после чего не будет знать где искать сущности,
4. после чего мы столкнемся с тем, что необходимой таблицы нет
5. после чего не будет знать на каком диалекте писать `CRETE TABLE...`

Поэтому для того, чтобы все это заработало нам необходимо

1. Сначала указать спрингу где искать репозитории
2. Создать бин с `DataSource`
3. Создать бин с `EntityManagerFactory`
4. Указать `entityManager`у где искать сущности
5. Указать `entityManager`у дополнительные свойства

## Решение

### Создадим бин `dataSource`

```java
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource(){
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    // нужно указать имя класса JDBC драйвера
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    // ↓↓↓↓ по-хорошему нужно создать свою БД и с ней работать ↓↓↓
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mak"); 
    // не правильно это, у постгреса базу отжимать
    // своего пользователя тоже неплохо было добавить
    dataSource.setUsername( "mak" ); // <-- замени имя пользователя
    dataSource.setPassword( "YOUR_PASSWORD" ); // <-- замени пароль
    return dataSource;
}
```

### Создадим бин `entityManager`

```java
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    em.setDataSource(dataSource()); // сюда прокидываем dataSource
    JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    return em;
}
```

### Указаем `entityManager`у где искать сущности

```java
em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.example.demo6.entity"});
```

вставить это можно непосредственно при создании `entityManager`а

### Создаем дополнительные свойства

в которых указываем hibernate, что нужно автоматически обновлять схемы и на каком диалекте писать запросы. За это отвечают свойства:

```
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
```

В коде это выглядит так:

```java
Properties additionalProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    // указываем HIBERNATE, чтобы он сам автоматически обновлял схемы
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
    // указываем HIBERNATE, на каком диалекте SQL писать запросы
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect");
    // осторожнее, у тебя может быть другая версия PostgreSQL
    return properties;
}
```

Далее нужно передать эти свойства `entityManager`у

```java
em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());
```

Сделать это  можно также непосредственно в методе создания `entityManager`а

### Создание конфигурации для работы с БД

Далее все это нам нужно будет упаковать куда-нибудь.
Для этого нам нужен будет какой-нибудь класс.
Пусть это будет `DataConfig`(название класса никакой роли не играет) и положим мы его в пакет `com.example.demo6.config`, потому что это конфиг

```java
package com.example.demo6.config;

public class DataConfig {
    // ...
}
```

чтобы спринг тоже понимал, что это конфиг проставим ему над классом аннотацию `@Configuration`

```java
package com.example.demo6.config;

@Configuration
public class DataConfig {
    // ...
}
```

### Укажем спрингу где искать репозитории

также не забудем, что мы хотели рассказать спрингу где искать репозитории
для этого над классом `DataConfig` укажем аннотацию `@EnableJpaRepositories("com.example.demo6.repository")`

```java
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.example.demo6.repository")
public class DataConfig {
    // ...
}
```

## Итого

```java
package com.example.demo6.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.Properties;

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.example.demo6.repository")
public class DataConfig {
    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource()); // сюда прокидываем dataSource
        // указываем где искать сущности
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.example.demo6.entity"});
        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        // прокидываем дополнительные свойства, которые:
        //  - расскажут спрингу что нужно автоматом обновлять схемы
        //  - расскажут спрингу на чем писать запросы
        em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());
        return em;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource(){
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        // нужно указать имя класса JDBC драйвера
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        // ↓↓↓↓ по-хорошему нужно создать свою БД и с ней работать ↓↓↓
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mak"); 
        // не правильно это, у постгреса базу отжимать
        // своего пользователя тоже неплохо было добавить
        dataSource.setUsername( "mak" ); // <-- замени имя пользователя
        dataSource.setPassword( "YOUR_PASSWORD" ); // <-- замени пароль
        return dataSource;
    }

    Properties additionalProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        // указываем HIBERNATE, чтобы он сам автоматически обновлял схемы
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        // указываем HIBERNATE, на каком диалекте SQL писать запросы
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect");
        // осторожнее, у тебя может быть другая версия PostgreSQL
        return properties;
    }
}
```

вроде все.

## Результат

После деплоя и запуска в базе появится новая таблица

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и успешно запустится приложение

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

## Примечания

> Все замечания, которые я делал в комментариях - можно откатить
> Я там напутал пакеты

Comment: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution

появилась вот такая ошибка. Я почитала, что это может быть связано с неправильным указанием бд/юзера/пароля, но перепроверила, все указано верно

Comment: ответил в чате https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133152/discussion-between---and-mak